# How to append information from AJAX request in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code and I need to create the following format of array:

```
var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

I have the following AJAX request and I receive all information correctly.

```
$.ajax({
    url:   '../get-route/46',
    type:  'get',
    success:  function (data) {
       $.each(data.poi, function(key, element) {
          console.log(element.name);
          console.log(element.latitud);
          console.log(element.longitud);
        });
    }
});
```

How can I append this information into an array called `location`?

Comment: You've got the name, lat and lng to place in the array - but what should the fourth value be?

Comment: because I need to get this information directly from this each.

Comment: No, I mean in your current array you have `4`, `5`, `3`, `2` and `1` as the final values in all child arrays. What is that value, and where should it come from in the `element` you retrieve through AJAX?

Comment: Inside the each just push a value. `locations.push([element.name, element.latitud, element.longitud, whateverthislastparamis]);`

Answer (score 1):

Above your ajax request declare a variable for the array:

```
var locations = [];
```

in your success callback, push to this array:

```
$.each(data.poi, function(key,element){
    locations.push([element.name, element.latitud, element.longitud, elemement.number]);
});
```

Comment: This is pushing the entire object, not an array to the `locations` array

Comment: edited, thanks. please consider reversing your down vote if my answer is better now.